# The custom tool 'DataServicesCoreClientGenerator' failed. ... error 0005: The 'OpenType' attribute is not allowed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, odata

When I add a service reference in Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition to a OData service for code generation, I get a schema error; error 0005 Open Type attribute is not supported. See images below.

The service is a OData v3-service. I'm using a Windows Forms project, .NET 4.5.1.

Does anybody know what's the problem?

[image: The service I'm trying to add]

[image: The exact error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took look at the service $metadata. It seems that the namespace of the csdl is of version 1 which is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm"

`<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm" Namespace="Cbs.OData">`

But OpenType is not supported in version 1. if you changed it to version 3 http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm, the client proxy code will be successfully generated.

So you should check your service to make sure your secsdl version is version 3.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me: 
"The element 'DataServices' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx' has invalid child element 'Schema' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm'. List of possible elements expected: 'Schema' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm'". Any suggestion on how to fix that one?

Comment: Ah, despite the above schema validation error in Visual Studio 2013, DataSvcUtil does generate code. Thanks :)